# Pandas add column of count of another column across all the datafram

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-science, data-munging

I have a dataframe:

```
df = C1  C2  E  
     1    2  3
     4    9  1
     3    1  1 
     8    2  8
     8    1  2
```

I want to add another columns that will have the count of the value that is in the columns 'E' in all the dataframe (in the column E)
So here the output will be:

```
df = C1. C2. E. cou 
     1.   2. 3.  1 
     4.   9. 1.  2
     3.   1. 1   2
     8.   2. 8.  1
     8.   1. 2.  1 #2 appears only one it the column E
```

How can it be done efficiently ?

Comment: @TimRoberts Right. I search only in column E

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way.  Find the matches and add them up.

```
import pandas as pd

data = [
    [1,2,3],[4,9,1],[3,1,1],[8,2,8]
]

df = pd.DataFrame( data, columns=['C1','C2','E'])
print(df)

def count(val):
    return (df['C1']==val).sum() + (df['C2']==val).sum()

df['cou'] = df.E.apply(count)
print(df)
```

Output:

```
   C1  C2  E
0   1   2  3
1   4   9  1
2   3   1  1
3   8   2  8
   C1  C2  E  cou
0   1   2  3    1
1   4   9  1    2
2   3   1  1    2
3   8   2  8    1
```

Comment: please notice that the count is within column E. I change the example to make it clearer

Comment: No, it's not.  The value you're SEARCHING for is in column E.  My result matches your desired result exactly.

Comment: please see the last edit

Comment: So, are you saying that columns C1 and C2 are totally irrelevant to the problem?  Then why did you include them, especially when their contents match your desired data?  I hope you can see how to change my code to sum up `df['E']` instead of `df['C1']` and `df['C2']`.

Comment: yes I just wonder is there a more efficient way to do it

Comment: You need to search the column once for every value.  You could iterate over the column and keep a running count yourself, I suppose, but you'd still have to apply the count as a new column at the end.